# How to make a discord bot edits its code?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, pycord

I have a discord bot (With Py-cord), and I want to have a command (Only I can use it) that makes a specific command not available to use, for example:

`/stop ban`

`/start mute`

So my idea is that the command will edit the guild_ids property and make the command only available for me to use, for example:

before:

```py
@slash_command()
```

after:

```py
@slash_command(guild_ids=[MY_SERVER_ID])
```

So my question: is it possible to do? and how to? and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You could store the guild IDs where a specific command is disabled in a database, check every time the command is run if the command is disabled in the guild and if it is: simply reply with something like "This command is disabled for this guild". Although, that wouldn't hide the slash command from the list when you type /

Comment: @jackssrt I believe there is a way to reload commands with `bot.sync_commands()`. However, I would not recommend doing this in production, because it may cause other issues.